# Do any/all database query optimizers ignore a join if nothing from one side of the join is selected?

Tags: sql, performance, join, query-optimization

Let's say I have what's below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id from users LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions on user_id = buyer_id;
```

Let's assume buyer_id has a foreign key relationship to user_id (does that matter?). Will a Query Optimizer be smart enough to ignore the join since the selection being made doesn't actually need anything from the "transactions" table?

Answer (score 1):

First, optimizers generally do not eliminate joins.  It is definitely an option.  And some optimizers might do it, particularly when the appropriate keys are declared to be `unique`.

More importantly, your query is not a case where that is even feasible.  The issue?  A user could have multiple transactions and the query would return multiple rows for that user.  Hence, it is not the same as just selecting from `users`.

Comment: good point, let's say its the case where I am selecting distinct user_id. I'll edit the question to reflect that

Comment: @NigerLittle-Poole . . . Then you would have a different question.  New questions should be asked as *new* questions not *comment*.

Answer (score 0):

This is what MS SQL says when running query

```
SELECT last_name FROM contact
LEFT JOIN orders
ON contact.id = orders.contact_id
```

.

```
(126295 row(s) affected)
Table 'contact'. Scan count 1, logical reads 979, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

As you can see, there is no mentioning of table orders. So my answer would be YES optimizer takes it into account. At least in MS SQL. But your mileage may vary.

The reason for this optimization is that in the output are data only from table users and table orders is joined with left join. So there is no dependency on data from table orders and thus it can be ignored.